# RAC in UK insisted on towing a automatic vehicle

Tags: automatic-transmission, towing

I have a 1.4 TFSI Audi A3.

The RAC in the UK insisted on towing it?

Could this have caused further damage to my vehicle?

Comment: Which wheels were on the road?

Comment: The recovery services in UK mostly carry a dolly trailer that lifts the front (driving) wheels off the ground, and you ride in the cab. They usually give you the choice, but it is a lot more work for them to set up the dolly than a tow bar, and a lot harder for you if they don't (you have to steer but you can't see the road ahead). The recovery agent is probably on "piece work", so if you were bullied into using a hitch when you wanted a proper tow, then make a complaint to the RAC.

Comment: VTC as requiring more detail. Car was towed how? Which wheels were on the ground, if any? Was the car's motor running?

Comment: car motor not running, all wheels on the ground

Comment: How far did they tow it with all the wheels on the road?

Comment: about 4 miles...

Comment: Your car manual will probably tell you the maximum allowed towing distance while the wheels are on the road.  It will also state a maximum towing speed.

Comment: Is your car a traditional automatic with a torque converter (in which case towing with the wheels on the ground is often a big issue), or is it an automated manual (eg, DSG) which probably have a true neutral?